# Spring Boot - Rest Assured methods not found

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, rest-assured

I have a REST API built with Spring Boot.

I am attempting to use Rest-Assured test framework, however I can't seem to get it to work.

I am using the guide from [Here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured)

```
get("/lotto").then().assertThat().body("lotto.lottoId", equalTo(5));
```

And have added the dependencies to my maven project.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, It doesn't seem to import the required classes and just prompts me to create a new "`get()"` method.

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class DemoControllerTest  {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        get("/lotto").then().assertThat().body("lotto.lottoId", equalTo(5));
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know much about rest assured. But shouldn't there be imports in Java class to use these methods.

Comment: I'm using eclipse to manage the imports. It's not suggesting anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing?

A simple `static` import, that's missing! In order to resolve the `get` static method, just use the following `static` import:

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;
```

Comment: Damn, I shouldn't rely on the IDE so much. Working now.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. What I did (using new version 3.0.2):

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Instead of:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

So I had same issue couldnt find the methods ...